# Having problems getting this multi level bootstrap 4 dropdown clone to mimc btn-dark style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I can't seem to figure out how to get this multi level bootstrap 4 clone dropdown menu to mimic the look of a bootstrap 4 btn-dark. The links and dropdown coloring are all off and the hover coloring and I'm not sure exactly what elements i'm supposed to be adjusting to match the look.   Any help would be great :).

```css
/* start multi level bootstrap style dropdown menu */
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color: #ccc;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>li{
 background-color: aqua;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
    border-left-color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
    float: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
    left: -100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle btn-dark" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
                <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Some action</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Some other action</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                  <a  class="dropdown-item" tabindex="-1" href="#">Hover me for more options</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li class="dropdown-item"><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Second level</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Even More..</a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">3rd level</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">another level</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">4th level</a></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">4th level</a></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">4th level</a></li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                            <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">3rd level</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Second level</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Second level</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit Fixed*

Create a CSS declaration using "ul.dropdown-menu.multi-level.show" to change the color in the background. It's added to the code snippet to change it to #343a40. :)

Just a tip for future reference, using chrome you can hit F12 and open the inspector. Inspect the element you want to change and see what it's declaration is.

Then create a declaration using "ul.dropdown-menu" to handle the lower branches.

```
ul.dropdown-menu.multi-level.show a:link{
color:white;
}
li.dropdown-item:focus, li.dropdown-item:hover {
background-color:#1d2124;
}
a.dropdown-item:hover {
background-color:#1d2124;
}
ul.dropdown-menu.multi-level.show {
background-color:#343a40;
}    
ul.dropdown-menu {
background-color:#343a40;
}
```

```css
/* start multi level bootstrap style dropdown menu */
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}
ul.dropdown-menu.multi-level.show a:link{
color:white;
}
li.dropdown-item:focus, li.dropdown-item:hover {
background-color:#1d2124;
}
a.dropdown-item:hover {
background-color:#1d2124;
}
ul.dropdown-menu.multi-level.show {
background-color:#343a40;
}    
ul.dropdown-menu {
background-color:#343a40;
}
.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color: #ccc;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>li{
 background-color: aqua;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
    border-left-color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
    float: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
    left: -100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle btn-dark" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
                <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Some action</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Some other action</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                  <a  class="dropdown-item" tabindex="-1" href="#">Hover me for more options</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li class="dropdown-item"><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Second level</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Even More..</a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">3rd level</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">another level</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">4th level</a></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">4th level</a></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">4th level</a></li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                            <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">3rd level</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Second level</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Second level</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: hey thank you so much! and also for the tip, I wasn't aware of that.